# Embedly API returns String instead JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, embedly

I'm testing the embedly API and I have a problem with what is returning. My code in Javascript is the followig which send the URL to PHP.

JAVASCRIPT

```
$.post('../../../services/rpc.php', 
    {functionName: 'getEmbed', 
    url: $('#story-post-new').val()},
    function(response){         
        $.each(response, function(index, val){
            ...
    });
})
```

PHP

```
$url = 'http://api.embed.ly/1/extract?url='.$_POST['url'].';key=xxx;';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
echo json_encode(curl_exec($ch));
```

So in PHP I call the api using extract, execute this url and finally do **json_encode** to the string returned. In Javascript the response is not a JSON Object and still being a String, so the **$.each** funcion doesn't work.

How can I return a JSON from PHP??

Thanks.

Comment: try `response = JSON.parse(response)` before your `.each` loop, it could be a json string

Comment: @LcLk returns me an error if I do that `unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON`, is like the String that Embed is returning me is not good...

Comment: COuld you look at the response body of the request in your browser's  console's network tab and post it here?

Comment: Or as taking a peak at embed.ly reveals: their data is already in JSON format, remove the `json_encode` from your PHP and try again, no need to encode twice

Comment: @LcLk Thanks, the problem is solved. Embedly returns a String with a number at the end of it and if I tried to `JSON.parse` obviously was wrong. Just a stupid thing...

Comment: well done fixing the problem and especially for letting us know, better than having question stubs all over SO. If you think anyone else may have the same problem, why not answer the question yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. What was happening? Embedly returns a String with a number at the end of it and if I tried to `JSON.parse` obviously was wrong. Just a stupid thing...